# How to mark victims in hector slam?

Tags: slam, navigation, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am using Hector_Slam for mapping.And I use hector_geotiff to save maps.But what  should  I do to mark victims on maps ?Any advice will be appreciated !Thank you very much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/154271/how-to-mark-victims-in-hector-slam?/) by [Yuichi Chu](https://answers.ros.org/users/9086/yuichi-chu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 148 on 2014-04-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See this [Q/A](http://answers.ros.org/question/58328/how-to-mark-a-detected-victim-in-hector-slam/) which is an earlier duplicate of your question by someone else. As noted also there, hector_object_tracker was called object_tracker before, so older launch files might not work out of the box.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yuichi Chu](https://answers.ros.org/users/9086/yuichi-chu/) on 2014-04-24**:
Stefan,Thank you very much!! I follow your advises and problems work out . much thanks again!

**Comment by [wsAndy](https://answers.ros.org/users/21662/wsandy/) on 2015-05-31**:
Hello Stefan! When I urn `hector_geotiff` ,  I get a error message like this `QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 3` . I don't know the reason.